# How to fix Nix errors "download-from-binary-cache.pl: still waiting for ... after 5 seconds"

Tags: nix

I am using Nix to install a complex development environment, and i get a lot of errors like in the title, specifically:

`download-from-binary-cache.pl: still waiting for ‘https://ryantrinkle.com:5443/23m7b0dssccafkhkyzv1f6j35kv245n8.narinfo’ after 5 seconds...
download-from-binary-cache.pl: still waiting for ‘https://ryantrinkle.com:5443/5y54f0g3xxr3r57n1f5r899574pwiggh.narinfo’ after 5 seconds...
download-from-binary-cache.pl: still waiting for ‘https://ryantrinkle.com:5443/2y4hcz6nr2g0smcjyslaiybz6df7j6pn.narinfo’ after 5 seconds...
download-from-binary-cache.pl: still waiting for ‘https://ryantrinkle.com:5443/9nis678v23ycd8h23p6k154msvk1iklb.narinfo’ after 5 seconds...
download-from-binary-cache.pl: still waiting for ‘https://ryantrinkle.com:5443/phkwwv8wi4mp3m4cqnpxvyvpd13gdj5k.narinfo’ after 5 seconds...
download-from-binary-cache.pl: still waiting for ‘https://ryantrinkle.com:5443/hb5xz24rjvqk1a97dds6013w215f0idh.narinfo’ after 5 seconds...
download-from-binary-cache.pl: still waiting for ‘https://ryantrinkle.com:5443/b9sy8sm9rzkak6miyvs32ssmjnnv32s4.narinfo’ after 5 seconds...`

I already met similar errors before with Nix, and i think that i solved it using some parameters for affecting parallelism, like `--jobs`, `--timeout` or similar. Now i cannot remember my solution nor find back the issue online, but i remember that several persons had a similar error. If i remember correctly the error was happening under some network conditions, like the internet service provider shaping your traffic or something similar.

Now i want to nail it once for all! I think that this is quite a common problem.

I am using Nix 1.10

Answer (score 0):

Alright found it https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/issues/9453 ... no wonder that i was not finding the original issue, it was deleted for some reason. Limiting parallel connections as explained there works for me

Answer (score 0):

Some routers can't cope with a large number of parallel connections. Configure

```
nix.extraOptions = ''
  binary-caches-parallel-connections = 50
'';
```

in `configuration.nix` (on NixOS) to reduce the amount of parallelism used by Nix. Nix users can configure that setting directly in `/etc/nix/nix.conf` (or whatever location you use to store that file).

EDIT: The next release of Nix will ship with that value set to 25 by default, so these issues should be a thing of the past soon: https://github.com/NixOS/nix/commit/c0d4173263a3077905643d5a044e982fc830f7ff.

Comment: Yes, thanks, this is explained in the Nix issue i linked above. In my case i found more convenient to use command line options

Comment: How do it on CentOS?

Comment: If you can't run `nixos-rebuild` due to this issue, how can you make that config option take effect in order to work around this issue?